# Activities unexpectedly killed

Tags: android, memory, out-of-memory, gwt-activities

I have 3 activities A, B, C. A activity has a fragment that holds a big amount of data. So does B. My problem is I go from A to B, and from B to C. And when i want to return from B to A with setResult() method. A activity starts from the beginning, not from onActivityResult(). I need help to solve the problem.

Comment: did you started activity for result?

Comment: yes i start from A activity, it is very big code. Its that ok if i post it here

Comment: post your code man..

Comment: can you please post your code so we can help you in right direction to solve your problem very quickly?

Comment: It is normal behavior. You don't have to post a lot of code. Just make three minimal activities that demonstrate the problem. Is good for your insight. In that onCreate look at its parameter when not null. It tells all.